# how to merge value of radio button with class through jquery

Tags: jquery, dom, radio-button, jquery-selectors

```
$check = $(this).closest('ul').parent().attr('id');
```

I have a "check" variable which value is "quiz1"

and this div(has id quiz1) contains radio button.
so i want value of radio button(has class option) which is checked inside quiz1.

so, i am using

```
 $value = $($check +' .option:checked').val();
// error: undefind
$value = $('#'+$check +' .option:checked').val();
//Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #[object Object] .option:checked
```

the main div generated using php

```
<div class="modal-body tab-pane container quiz-list" id="quiz<?= $i ?>">
                      <h4><?= $i . "." ?> <?= $rowForQuiz['question'] ?> </h4>
                      <h4 class="mt-4"><input type="radio" name="quizoption[]" value="A"><label for="A"> <?= $rowForQuiz['optiona'] ?></label></h4>
                      <h4><input type="radio" class="option" name="quizoption[]" value="B"><label for="B"> <?= $rowForQuiz['optionb'] ?></label></h4>
                      <h4><input type="radio" class="option" name="quizoption[]" value="C"><label for="C"> <?= $rowForQuiz['optionc'] ?></label></h4>
                      <h4><input type="radio" class="option" name="quizoption[]" value="D"><label for="D"> <?= $rowForQuiz['optiond'] ?></label></h4>
                      <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                          <a class="custome-btn" data-toggle="pill" href="#quiz<?= $i+1 ?>">NEXT</a>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $('.custome-btn').click(function(){
          $check = $(this).closest('ul').parent().attr('id');
          $value = $('#'+$check+' .option:checked').val();
          console.log($value);
        });
      });
    </script>
```

Comment: `id` selector should start with `#`.

Comment: yes i know that

Comment: Show your html as well.

Comment: added in question

Comment: @VikashSDNT when are you calling you script

Comment: script is before </html> tag

Comment: It must be before `</body>` tag. You cannot have anything between `</body>` and `</html>`.

Comment: $value = $('#'+$check+' .option:checked').val(); using this but still getting error

Comment: Post the code in your question, not in comments. And post the error message as well.

Comment: yes it is before </body>.. it is working when putting value directly like  $value = $('#quiz1 .option:checked').val();

Comment: @VikashSDNT there is one extra }); in your script, remove it and try

Comment: that is for document.ready i forget to remove close tag from script

Answer (score 0):

Check this one.You can get the result by this way. i haven't change the name, value and id that you are getting dynamically by php.

```
$('#'+variablename).find('input:radio:checked').each(function()
```

```js
$('.custome-btn').click(function(){

var qn = $(this).closest('ul').parent().attr('id');

 $('#'+qn).find('input:radio:checked').each(function(){
            v = $(this).val();
        
        console.log(v);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal-body tab-pane container quiz-list" id="quiz1">
                      <h4><?= $i . "." ?> <?= $rowForQuiz['question'] ?> </h4>
                      <h4 class="mt-4"><input type="radio" name="quizoption[]" value="A"><label for="A"> <?= $rowForQuiz['optiona'] ?></label></h4>
                      <h4><input type="radio" class="option" name="quizoption[]" value="B"><label for="B"> <?= $rowForQuiz['optionb'] ?></label></h4>
                      <h4><input type="radio" class="option" name="quizoption[]" value="C"><label for="C"> <?= $rowForQuiz['optionc'] ?></label></h4>
                      <h4><input type="radio" class="option" name="quizoption[]" value="D"><label for="D"> <?= $rowForQuiz['optiond'] ?></label></h4>
                      <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                          <a class="custome-btn" data-toggle="pill" href="#quiz<?= $i+1 ?>">NEXT</a>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
```